# how to create my own color name

Tags: javascript, jquery

Given the following statement:

```
$('#upLatImb').append('<span style="color:#F62817; text-decoration:blink">' + sprintf("%11.0f",fCargoLatMom).replace(/ /g,'&nbsp;') + '</span');
```

I would like to do something like:

```
var problemcolor=0xF62817;
$('#upLatImb').append('<span style="color:problemcolor; text-decoration:blink">' + sprintf("%11.0f",fCargoLatMom).replace(/ /g,'&nbsp;') + '</span');
```

but that results in numerous html errors.

I could, of course, do a search and replace across all .js files to change the color, but I'd like to use logical names if possible and only change one statement per color.

I'm just barely above absolute novice level, so all suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: first bit of advice: don't use blinking text.

Comment: @Joseph Is there a technical reason for avoiding blinking text? In my instance I'm replacing a DOS C program originally written in 1988, and the users are used to seeing the blinking. If they don't notice the problem and the airplane leaves the ground, the FAA fine will be in the tens of thousands.

Comment: My comment was made mostly in jest.  Blinking text is notoriously hated on websites and has almost no purpose in HTML.  (it was even [conceived in a drunken stupor](http://www.montulli.org/theoriginofthe%3Cblink%3Etag)).  But your application is the first and only legitimate use of it I have ever seen. :P

Comment: An aircraft flight control system will be replaced by a web-based app? God help us all...

Comment: @NullUserException ఠ_ఠ Relax, this has nothing to do with the flight control firmware. This is software used before a flight to ensure that 747 freighters are loaded within balance and weight limitations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It looks like you want something memorable for repetitive use?

Create a CSS class with the "color: #F62817" property and apply the class instead of inline styles, which aren't usually preferred.

So, your CSS:

```
.problemcolor {
    color: #F62817;
}

.blink {
    text-decoration: blink;
}
```

And your jQuery:

```
$('#upLatImb').append('<span class="problemcolor blink">' + sprintf("%11.0f",fCargoLatMom).replace(/ /g,'&nbsp;') + '</span');
```

No concatenation here! This results in cleaner HTML/CSS and is better practice, and memorable, all at once.

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
var problemcolor = '#f62817';
$('#upLatImb').append('<span style="color: ' + problemcolor + '; text-decoration:blink">' + sprintf("%11.0f",fCargoLatMom).replace(/ /g,'&nbsp;') + '</span>');
```

Answer (score 2):

You could concatenate your string with something like:

```
var problemcolor=0xF62817;
$('#upLatImb').append('<span style="color:' + problemcolor + '; text-decoration:blink">' + sprintf("%11.0f",fCargoLatMom).replace(/ /g,'&nbsp;') + '</span');
```

Answer (score 1):

Also consider the jQuery `CSS` and `appendTo` methods.

```
var problemcolor = '#FFFFFF';
$('<span>Your span</span>').appendTo('3upLatImb').css('color', problemcolor);
```